# how to give different file name every time i capture video and write it to file?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am newbee in opencv. I am working on part of the project.

In the below code, I have used **VideoWriter** class to store video with name **MyVideo.avi** as I specified in below code.
But every time i capture video it stores with same name i.e it get overridden.
**So I want to name it with computer date and time.
please help me to modify this**

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0

if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
{
    cout << "ERROR: Cannot open the video file" << endl;
    return -1;
}

namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

 double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

cout << "Frame Size = " << dWidth << "x" << dHeight << endl;

Size frameSize(static_cast<int>(dWidth), static_cast<int>(dHeight));

 VideoWriter oVideoWriter ("D:/MyVideo.avi", CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'), 20, frameSize, true); //initialize the VideoWriter object 

 if ( !oVideoWriter.isOpened() ) //if not initialize the VideoWriter successfully, exit the program
{
    cout << "ERROR: Failed to write the video" << endl;
    return -1;
}

while (1)
{

    Mat frame;

    bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

    if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
   {
         cout << "ERROR: Cannot read a frame from video file" << endl;
         break;
    }

     oVideoWriter.write(frame); //writer the frame into the file

    imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

    if (waitKey(10) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
   {
        cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
        break; 
   }
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the date and time yourself?

Comment: @NathanOliver i have searched a lot. Then i came up with idea of looping videoWriter class. i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename is hardcoded in your source code.

When initializing `oVideoWriter` object, use this code instead:

```
const QString filename = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss") + ".avi";
VideoWriter oVideoWriter(filename, CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'), 20, frameSize, true);
```

This will set filename to the current date and time. [Read the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString) on date/time formatting.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to create filenames during runtime:

### Creation by string

```
std::string filename = "image";
filename += "_001";
filename += ".img";
```

### Creation by `ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream name_stream;
name_stream << "image" << 2 << ".img";
std::string filename = name_stream.str();
```

### Creation by `snprintf`:

```
char buffer[128];
int chars_printed = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),
                             "image_%03d.img",
                              3);
std::string filename(buffer);
```

The may be more methods to create filenames, but these examples should suffice.  Choose one that suits your needs.